# Не отправлять цель с кнопки в Яндекс.Метрику при незаполненных полях

Tags: javascript, yandex-metrika-api

Здравствуйте. Как сделать так, чтобы цель с кнопки не отправлялась в Яндекс.Метрику при незаполненных полях "e-mail" и "телефон"?

Сайт на Битриксе, код формы такой:

```
<form data-action="feedback" class="regis">
    <div class="heading"><?=$arParams['TITLE']?></div>

    <div class="regis__txt"><?=$arParams['TEXT']?></div>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="e-mail">
    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="ваш телефон" data-tel>

    <button class="regis__sub" onclick="yaCounter35127730.reachGoal('service'); return true;">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, нашёл такое решение:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {

    var x = document.forms["service"]["email"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        return false;
    };

    var x = document.forms["service"]["phone"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        return false;
    }

}
</script>

<form name="service" data-action="feedback" class="regis" onsubmit="yaCounter35127730.reachGoal('service'); return validateForm()">
    <div class="heading"><?=$arParams['TITLE']?></div>

    <div class="regis__txt"><?=$arParams['TEXT']?></div>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="e-mail" data-email required>
    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="ваш телефон" data-tel required>

    <button class="regis__sub">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто повесь тригер на отправку формы, должно получится если Битрикс своего чего-то не навешивает при сабмите...

```
<form data-action="feedback" class="regis" onsubmit="yaCounter35127730.reachGoal('service'); return true;">
    <div class="heading"><?=$arParams['TITLE']?></div>

    <div class="regis__txt"><?=$arParams['TEXT']?></div>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="e-mail">
    <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="ваш телефон" data-tel>

    <button class="regis__sub">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

а вообще с этой формой получается можно отправить что угодно в этих полях,
я бы изменил type на email и tel соотвественно

Comment: Дмитрий, попробовал так. Все равно цели достигаются.